# MVC routes are in conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to have 2 routes in my ASP.NET MVC application, and I am having difficulty trying to define the routes in a way that they don't steal from each other.

1. I need to handle urls like

> www.website.com/Home/About
>
> www.website.com/Home/Contact

2. I also need to urls like this

> www.website.com/23a244x3/Products/2
>
> www.website.com/434e5s344/Services/1
>
> www.website.com/f2432g423/Profile

So I need 2 routes.

The urls in #1 are successfully handled by the default route, which is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

To handle the urls in #2, I have defined the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PagesRoute",
    url: "{uniqueID}/{action}/{pagecount}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Pages", pagecount = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Unfortunately now the route #2 (aka PagesRoute) is also handling the urls from #1, such as www.website.com/Home/About. I also have url rewrite rules set in IIS that turn all urls into lowercase, for SEO purposes, so /Home redirects to /home etc.

How can I differentiate these two routes? The route in #2 seems to be greedy..

Comment: How is it supposed to differentiate? They're essentially the exact same route

Comment: Well, in case #1, the first parameter in the url is the name of a controller, whereas in case #2, the first parameter in the url is an alphanumeric code that is not the name of a controller.

Comment: Both routes are the same because they contain 3 segments and each segment can contain any value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to not provide controller, and provide routes for each controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

To the parser `{uniqueID}` and `{controller}` are essentially the same. Any string in the Url, will match both routes, so you need something to differentiate the 2.

You can also take a look into [Route Constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PagesRoute",
    "{uniqueID}/{action}/{pagecount}",
    new { controller = "Pages", pagecount = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { uniqueID = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. In reality I have other controllers as well, not just a /Home controller. So if I use this method, I would actually need to define a route for each of those controllers. This is what I was trying to avoid :)

Comment: I've added another example @Gary

Comment: I'd actually looked at that same Route Constraints page earlier, and didn't use it because the "\d+" regex is for digits only, whereas my uniqueids are alphanumeric. If I change it to a "\w+" to capture alphanumeric characters then I will be back to the same problem :(

Comment: Specify all lowercase `[a-z0-9]+`. Anything with a capital letter won't be matched (ie. Home, Pages, etc...)

Comment: I didn't put this in the question, but I have url rewrite rules set in IIS that turn all urls into lowercase, for SEO purposes, so /Home redirects to /home etc. (I know, I know, I am working with too many constraints!). I think I will have to decide between your original suggestion (create separate routes for each controller), or change the url for case #2 to something that can be uniquely targeted by a route

Comment: Fine, one last suggestion. If all the provided uniqueIDs contain a letter and a number, then use this: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$`

Comment: Did that work for you? How did you end up solving this?

Comment: I used your first suggestion, since changing the case 2 urls was not an option.